# Laravel 5.2 How to populate edit form with multiple select?

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2

I want to create a zone which contain few cities. So I decided to use jQuery Select2

Here is my create form multiple selection

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('cities') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label>Tentukan Kota</label>
                    <select name="cities[]" class="city form-control" data-placeholder="Pilih Kota" style="width: 100%;" multiple="multiple">
                    @foreach($cities as $city)
                    <option value="{{ $city->id }}">{{ $city->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                    </select>

                </div>
```

I can multiple select just like in documentation.

Here is my controller which handle display create form

```
public function zone_create()
{
    $cities = City::where('zone_id', null)->get();
    return view('backend.admin.pricings.zone_create', compact('cities'));
}
```

The relationship is One Zone Has Many City.

```
class Zone extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',    
    ];

    public function cities(){
        return $this->hasMany(City::class);    
    }
}
```

The city belongs to zone

```
class City extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'zone_id',
        'name',    
    ];

    public function zone(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Zone::class);    
    }
}
```

Here is my edit method

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $zone = Zone::find($id);
    $cities = City::all();
    return view('backend.admin.pricings.zone_edit', compact('zone', 'cities'));
}
```

Here is my edit form so far

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('cities') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                    <label>Tentukan Kota</label>
                    <select name="cities[]" class="city form-control" data-placeholder="Pilih Kota" style="width: 100%;" multiple="multiple">
                    //load option from cities table
//set selected the city belongs to zone
//the other city which don't belong to zone still here for option
                    </select>

                </div>
```

But how I can populate my edit form (multiple selection) with City belongs to zone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just like this in my view

```
<select name="cities[]" class="city form-control" data-placeholder="Pilih Kota" style="width: 100%;" multiple="multiple">
                    @foreach($cities as $city)
                        @if(in_array($city->id, $zoneCityIds))
                        <option value="{{ $city->id }}" selected="true">{{ $city->name }}</option>
                        @else
                        <option value="{{ $city->id }}">{{ $city->name }}</option>
                        @endif 
                    @endforeach
                    </select>
```

and like this in my controller

```
public function zone_edit($id)
    {
        $zoneCityIds = [];
        $zone = Zone::find($id);
        $cities = City::all();
        foreach($zone->cities as $zoneCity)
        {
            $zoneCityIds[] = $zoneCity->id;
        }        

        return view('backend.admin.pricings.zone_edit', compact('zone', 'cities', 'zoneCityIds'));
    }
```

actually it's jus about option tag `selected="true"`

Answer (score 2):

for multiple values simply use

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('Categories') !!}<br />
    {!! Form::select('categories[]', $cost_centers, 
        $post->categories->pluck('id')->toArray(), 
        ['class' => 'form-control', 
        'multiple' => 'multiple']) !!}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your edit function you can get all the cities of that particular zone

`$zone_cities = implode(',',$zone->cities->lists('name')->toArray());`

and pass `$zone_cities` in your view.

```
return view('backend.admin.pricings.zone_edit', compact('zone', 'cities','zone_cities'));
```

You will have to use Form Model binding in your view 
Read about laravel collective form model binding [here].[1](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html#form-model-binding)

You will open your form like this

Your Edit form will be like this

```
{!! Form::label('cities','Cities: ') !!}
{!! Form::text('cities',$zone_cities,['class'=>'input','id'=>'cities','aria-required'=>'true','data-seperator'=>',']) !!}
```

Comment: How to do that without form model binding? and it should `select` not input text.